# How to fix 'Your PHP installation appears to be missing the SQLSrv extension which is required by Project Nami' for windows

Tags: php

I recently installed project nami on my pc, but when I open a local server on my computer I get the error which I quoted on the title of this post. When I check my terminal, the following text in highlighted in red:

> [::1]:63946 [500]: GET /wp-admin/setup-config.php

I am not sure which extension project nami requires, but to clear things up I use mysql for all of the php database work - specifically **mysqli**, and I have also the php_mysqli extension enabled in my php.ini file, but I still get the same error.

Is there a way to fix this error with mysql as my database of choice or is project nami incompatible with mysql. The reason I am asking this question is because whenever I add a normal sql extension -**php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64**- I get the following error:

> There has been a critical error on this website

Comment: If nami says that sqlsrv is required, it's unlikely you can use a different DBMS.

Comment: I removed the mysqli tag as your question seems to be asking about SQL Server extension. This has nothing to do with MySQL or mysqli extension

Comment: So you are saying project nami can use mysql? If so, how can I fix this error and make this work.